# Ubuntu freeze at login screen

Tags: 16.04, boot, login-screen, freeze

I use Ubuntu 16.04 kernel 4.10.0-38. It boots normally, and at the login screen it shows up the password box, then freezes at this point

- The cursor blinks for few seconds and then stops.
- I can't move the mouse or type on the keyboard.

Specs:

- CPU: core i7-3630qm
- GPU: Radeon HD 7610m
- RAM: 6GB DDR3
- HDD: 1TB ~ 100GB for the Ubuntu partition

Comment: Please [edit] and post the hardware specifications.

Comment: I edited it now but yet no answer

Answer (score 0):

I too need a solution to this problem. I am using Ubuntu 16.04. After boot, the cursor blinks at the password input field and then freezes; while it blinks, typing in my password does not work.

The problem occurred after the computer woke up from a suspend due to low battery. When I plugged in the charger the computer came back up and froze at the password field. After that no matter how many restarts I do the issue persists.

Lenovo Flex Pad 15, 8GB, Intel Core i5-4200U @1.60hz, 2.30hz.

These guys solved it by doing this:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/368748/ubuntu-16-04-gui-freezes-on-login-start-page

Boot in Recovery Mode and Enable Networking -

```
apt-get update
apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-all
apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
apt-get install ubuntu-minimal
apt-get install xorg xserver-xorg
apt-get install xserver-xorg-input-evdev

reboot
```